# Weird data mangling when connection is over the internet

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Im using https://github.com/gaby64/sf

When i connect localy over 127.0.0.1 everything is fine
This is a 32 byte fragment of the data i should get and do get locally:

00000000
00000000
00000000
00000100
00000000
00001010
01000111
01000101
01010100
01000001
01010000
01010000
01010000
01001011
01000111
00000000
11111111
11101000
01111011
00100000
00100010
01101001
01101101
01100111
00100010
00111010
00100000
01011011
00100000
01011101
00101100
00100000

This is the data i get when connecting via my own external internet ip:

00100000
00100000
00100000
00100000
00100000
00100000
00100000
00100000
01011100
00101111
01011100
00101111
00100000
01100100
01110010
01101001
01101100
01101100
00100000
01100100
01101111
01110111
01101110
00100000
01110100
01101111
00100000
01110100
01101000
01100101
00100000
01101001

it appears to be completely mixed and is mostly NULL, for the 84kb multipart message that is.
small messages dont seem to be affected.

is there something i am failing to consider?
A few months ago it was working, since then i had to reinstall linux so i cannot test with exactly the same conditions i had when it was functional.

And there is another bit of weirdness, a web page served using libwebsockets only loads partially up to 20kb when i try to access it via my external ip, also works fine through localhost.

I should mention its all repeatable, always getting transformed the same way.

ran wire-shark to analyze traffic, im not much of an expert on tcp/ip protocol but looks like everything is ok when looking at the packets. kernel must be responsible, could my application have a leak that effects that kernel? despite no warnings from valgrind.

Comment: You are keeping mind that under TCP, send() and recv() may send anywhere between zero and all of the bytes you passed to them, and that if they do send/recv only a partial buffer, you are handling that correctly?

Comment: yes i am. regardless tho, how would that affect it working locally vs passing through the ISP switch/router?   [\n]

im also logging each send and it seems to be fine   
    [\n]
  the data is wrong after the 5th byte

Comment: Do you account for endianness?  ntohl (network to host) and htonl (host to network)

Comment: unless the ISP is unpacking the packets and interpreting my data and repacking it, that shouldnt matter. host and guest are the same machine. the functions i use to serialize 32bit and 16bit numbers does convert to network byte order and back i believe.

Comment: Well I suppose the ISP could be munging the data; you could try it with a different ISP to see if it's broken there too.  That said, if we assume the ISP is working correctly it would still be possible that there is a bug in your code that only shows its symptoms under certain conditions, and sending the data through your ISP meets those conditions while your local testing does not.  (timing and packetization-boundaries are one thing that would likely be different, which is why I asked about your send and recv handling)

Comment: have you looked at my socket framework?  you will find the read call on line 1145 of sf.c

Comment: i have just tested and logged to a file every segment of data send successfully sent, the data in the file is in the expected order, it cannot be my program. could the kernel be responsible?

Comment: `ev.h` is missing in you git repo.

Comment: you have to install libev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, 
i was not ware that TCP cannot traverse NAT routers.

connecting directly to my modem solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use some method to check if you receive the same that you have sent. There are many ways to do this. One well known and easy to find on the Internet is the checksum method. Search for it.

Comment: TCP/IP should already take care of packetloss and ordering.  
the data should not be garbled the same way every-time, why would it happen sending the traffic through my ISP and not happen when just using the localhost?